# Problem with the primary decomposition theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I need to use the primary decomposition theorem in the linear transformation $T:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ defined by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ -6 & -11 & -6 \\ \end{pmatrix}$

I found that the minimal polynomial is $\lambda(\lambda+5)(\lambda+1)$ (which is also the characteristic polynomial) so by the primary decomposition theorem I have that $\mathbb R^3=ker(T)\oplus ker(T+5Id)\oplus ker(T+Id)$ but the problem here is that $ker(T)=\{0\}=ker(T+5Id)$ and $ker(T+Id)=\{a(1,-1,1): a\in \mathbb R\}$, so I don´t know what I´m doing wrong. Can you please help me?

Comment: that, is not the minimal neither the characteristic polynomial: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=characteristic+polynomial+%7B%7B0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B-6%2C-11%2C-6%7D%7D